# Can't resolve my library from jcenter

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

I uploaded new library to bintray successfully and linked it to jcenter.
Everything worked well so I uploaded another artifact to the same package in bintray.
I can see the files in bintray with the right version, but still after 4 days I can't resolve the aar using the

```
compile 'your.package:artificat:version'
```

The first artifact is available but the new one is not.
What may be wrong?

Comment: check the files you have uploaded. This can happen because the files are not packaged properly

Comment: Everything looks good,still can't use my library from jcenter

Comment: Generally there 2 issues either the library files packaging, which includes your aar, pom etc. other is making the snapshot available on jfrog. Make sure you have selected the checkbox for hosting snapshots on jfrog. You might want to log in and check the state on jfrog

Comment: How do you make the snapshot available?

Comment: Can you share details about the package you are trying to update? did you added files to an existing version or created a new one? can you download the new files from your copy of the package but not from JCenter?

Comment: I solved it with deleting the old files and upload again.